# Spring Boot Only Finds Beans in current and sub packages - how do you obtain reuse

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring boot only find beans within the current packages or sub packages.  I am creating several services that reuse beans and packages - how do I do this?  Do I need to use the java implementation and forget autoscan?

Tim

Comment: You should use @ComponentScan and tell to spring all the packages you wan to scan. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Comment: Or move your application class to the most available top level package (this is what I generally do) instead of in its own package or sub package already.

Comment: You should also look at using the Spring Boot autoconfiguration hooks to automatically import `@Configuration` classes for each of your reusable jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use @ComponentScan and tell to spring all the packages you wan to scan. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

You don't need to do that

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(KafkaMqttBridgeConfig.class);
```

And instead to implement BeanFactoryAware use

```
@Autowired private KafkaMqttBridge bridge;
```

This should works

**UPDATE**

I have modified some classes and now it works.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

SpringBootTestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class SpringBootTestController {

    @Autowired
    public SpringBootTestController(SpringBootTest springBootTest) {
        springBootTest.fakeMethod();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return the get method that return the service info and statistics
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getServiceInfo() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work - not sure why - still serems to only scan from current package on down.

Comment: I got it to work by adding the code below to my controller - once I did this all the other dependencies with Autowired worked.  Weird thing is I put a breakpoint on the default constructor of the class I got through the bean factory and the it was never hit.   @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory bf) throws BeansException {
        bridge = (KafkaMqttBridge)bf.getBean("kafkaMqttBridge");
        if (!this.bridge.run()) System.exit(1);
    }

Comment: can you add or share your configuration, please?

Comment: I think that you can edit your answer adding the code and delete your code from the answer section. Can you add the package for each class, please?

Comment: Added the comment - when I add "com.groupcaretech" to the scan and remove the code you told me to the application fails right away with this excetion:

Comment: Can you add the exception, please?

Comment: Added it to my answer so it would fit

Comment: This is the error No qualifying bean of type [com.groupcaretech.security.ssl.groupcaresslfactory.GroupCareSslFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: sslFactoryBouncyCastleImpl,GroupCareSslFactory. So basically you have to add Qualifier annotation with Autowired together telling which of both bean you want to use. This exception means that you have 2 beans and you have to decide which of them use.

Comment: Thank you!  Although I still have the issue where in my controller I need the following code to set the bean:

Comment: public class KafkaMqttBridgeController implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private KafkaMqttBridge bridge;
   
    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory bf) throws BeansException {
        bridge = (KafkaMqttBridge)bf.getBean("kafkaMqttBridge");
        if (!this.bridge.run()) System.exit(1);
    }
 If I take out the BeanAware code and make the bridge autowired I do not get an exception by the object reference is null.

Comment: Can you prepare a demo and upload to github in order to see all the configuration?

Comment: Added link to project that some the issue with little code - seems so easy I must be doing something wrong

Comment: I have updated my answer in order to solve your problem